# iPhone MPMoviePlayerController lost sound while playing video on a real device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-player

I am having issue with losing "video" sound while it was playing.

I followed all the standards but the Video/Audio sometimes gets muted or just disappears at the end of the video file. I have no idea why. Does any know what might be the issue?

This only happens when running the app on the real device, I can't reproduce the issue on the simulator.

Could a "didReceiveMemory" warning cause this? I sometimes receive this message when it happens.

The video file is being streamed via a URL address, format in MPEG-4 Movie, size less than 6.2 MB.

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction) playMovie:(NSString*)theUrl
           setMovieType:(NSString *)theType
          setPlayOption:(int)theOption
setSenderUIButton:(UIButton *)  thisSender
{
    NSString *getvdoUrl = [[NSString alloc]  initWithString:theUrl];
    NSURL *thisVdoURL = [NSURL  URLWithString:getvdoUrl];
    [getvdoUrl release];
    getvdoUrl =  nil;
    MPMoviePlayerController *movieplayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:thisVdoURL];       
    thisVdoURL = nil;
     if (movieplayer)
    {
        self.vdoPlayer = movieplayer;
         [movieplayer release];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                    object:self.vdoPlayer];
        [self.vdoPlayer play];   
    }

}

-(void)  moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)theNotification
{



     MPMoviePlayerController *movieplayer= [theNotification object];    
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
      object:movieplayer];   
    movieplayer.initialPlaybackTime =  0.0;   
    [movieplayer stop];           
}
```

Below are the warning messages. I received them before the Video file started to play:

```
warning:  Unable to read symbols for 
"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3
(7E18)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/VCH263.videodecoder"
(file  not found).


warning: Unable to read symbols for 
"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3
(7E18)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/H264H1.videodecoder"
(file  not found).


warning: Unable to read symbols for 
"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3
(7E18)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH1.videodecoder"
(file  not found).

2010-03-29 16:57:25.830 ....
v2[4663:207] setting 
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/7DCB1FCC-7268-4551-B737-8B418CA4A07E/tmp/MediaCache/[html]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try a different MP4 file, they are not all equal - they should be optimized for streaming if you are creating them from Quicktime - "hinted" if your create them with the help of mp4box for example. There could be issue with your file audio timestamps - try playing it via safari browser and/or quicktime if there would be any issues . I guess you follow the maximum bitrate/profile/level settings for H264 and AAC as well .

If you really are running out of memory in your phone, this can happen, the mediaplayer runs in separated process- not direcly in your application (I guess to allow it to use GPU decoder and sandbox it).
Are you playing this video just once in the app ? Are you removing the notification afterwards? - it is usually enough to register it just once even before playing video.

Something depends on which firmware are you compiling under and running under, bugs tend to be fixed in later versions, but from 4.0 whole API changed and code needs to be updated as well...

The warning messages are useless and common for simulator - they are just from simulator trying to reach debugging symbols for modules outside of SDK - as simulator's Quicktime runs through your desktop Quicktime - you may see your soundcard driver and more codecs there depending on your setup.